# Chatbanned user can still join chat with offensive user names

Tags: support, chat, offensive

[This fine gentleman](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/108256/pliz-make-me-cum-in-ur-haus) is apparently chatbanned, but continues to join various rooms over and over (possibly in an automated fashion). His current name is intentionally offensive, as are his previous ones and it seems that despite being chatbanned, he can still join over and over and over, causing his name to be displayed prominently in the "descent from the top of the screen" animation.

In fact, he's even been [copying chat transcripts about himself and pasting them as questions on sites that he isn't banned on](https://askubuntu.com/q/417031). (weird, right?)

What recourse is there for a user like this?

Comment: [If you're a praying man, I recommend this.](http://www.juxtapost.com/site/permlink/8cc22570-6b4a-11e1-878e-1d275c233180/post/dear_lord_please_grant_me_the_ability_to_punch_people_in_the_face_over_the_internet_/)

Comment: He just... posted here. :(

Comment: Does he realize that if he posts another answer that it will be auto-protected, and he won't be able to post here anymore?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Well, he probably does now.  Not sure you did anyone any favors by cluing him into that, honestly.

Comment: @HopelessN00b he did a favor to SE developers, they will come up with more strict stuff to stop this none sense in the future, hopefully...

Comment: There is a system that will stop him at some point from even joining any chat rooms. A simple suspension won't do this, and probably shouldn't.

Comment: @MadScientist well it now says "This user is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 1 hour 7 minutes" is this the system you mentioned? (by the way it's not true, he's not suspended on any site)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I mean something else that is not connected to suspensions. I don't really want to elaborate on that here though to avoid giving that user any information that could be used to evade it (the exact details are also not known to moderators as well).