# Suspended users can still edit their chat profiles

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, account-suspension

Suspended users can still join chat and edit their chat profiles. This is sometimes used as a workaround for communicating, and in the worst cases can be used to spread offensive content, etc.

Suspended users should not be able to log into the chat system at all, or at minimum should not be able to edit profiles.

Somewhat related, as far as communication workarounds go: [Chatbanned user can still join chat with offensive user names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219815/chatbanned-user-can-still-join-chat-with-offensive-user-names)

Bug if this is not intentional, feature request if it is by design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like a good dupe (plus some) to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a dupe spree tonight.